# is it possible to convert yaml and properties interact using typescript

Tags: typescript, properties, yaml

I am tried to write a little tool that could let me convert the yaml and properties each other by using typescript. what I am tried to do like this, fisrt install dependencies:

```
npm install js-yaml properties
```

when write a function like this:

```
const convertYamlToProperties = () => {
        const yamlData = YAML.safeLoad('yaml string');
        const properties = stringify(yamlData);
        return (<div className="jwt-payload">{properties}</div>);
    }
```

and load the dependencies like this:

```
import * as YAML from 'js-yaml';
import { stringify } from 'properties';
```

maybe the properties is too old and did not maintain for a long time, I could not import the dependencies smoothly. Shows error in Visual Studio Code like this:

```
Cannot find module 'properties' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
No quick fixes available
```

The react version is 18. what should I do to convert the yaml to properties? this is the key version info:

```
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

Comment: "I could not import the dependencies smoothly" - what exactly happen? Did you get an error? Are you missing TS types? Please provide some information we can go on

Comment: I have pasted the error message.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an existing `@types/properties` definition on NPM. What you can do is supply your own types.

You can start with an "any" type to just allow you to use it immediately, but if you want to implement autocomplete you might want to be a bit more specific with your types.

Here is an example of the `stringify` function in `properties`:

```
declare module 'properties' {
  export interface StringifyOptions {
    path: string;
    comment: string
    separator: string
    unicode: boolean
    replacer(this: {
      isProperty: boolean;
      isSection: boolean;
      assert:() => any;
    }, key: string, value: unknown, section: string | null);
  }
  export function stringify(obj: object, options?: Partial<StringifyOptions>, callback: (error: any, value: string) => void);
}
```

Either put this in a `.ts` file or a `.d.ts` file, either of which should be imported into the project in some way, either by using `import` or adding it into `tsconfig.json`'s `files` or `include`